# Highcharts to show drill down charts to different container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a sales data, that need to be drill-down to N level, in different container.

for example: first chart will be showing country wise sales, clicking on a country it drill down to state wise chart in different container, not overlapping the first chart... clicking on the state further drill down to district wise sales on different part.

Please help me.. struggle a lot to create one like this

Answer (score 0):

Drilldown is based on appropriate series figure, so if you prepare many levels of data point you can have any level of deep :

http://jsfiddle.net/2tjPp/

```
data = [{
                y: 55.11,
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'MSIE versions',
                    categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                    data: [{
                        y: 10.85,
                        drilldown: {
                            name: 'MSIE versions',
                            categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                            data: [4,3,2,1],
                            color: colors[0]
                        }
                    },
                    7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
            }]
```